# Code never enters in foreach through SPGridView.Rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, foreach

I've a problem that make me mad...
I've a simple SPGridView:
[image]

In the report field there are hyperlink controls that point to a page, passing a query string id, that generates the pdf file with some code that hasn't been made by me. To explain better:

- First row has NavigationUrl="/Pages/Report.aspx?ID_REPORT=1"
- Second row has NavigationUrl="/Pages/Report.aspx?ID_REPORT=3"

And this feature works. When I click on a url the report has been generated and correctly the browser asks if I want to download the file.

The feature that I'm trying to implement is the multiple report download, those has the checkbox checked, in a single zip file. So I added Ionic.Zip.dll to the solution and made a method with the report generation code that returns a byte array:

```
private byte[] getFileBytes(string id)
{
try
{
    byte[] file = null;

    bool isAdmin = Utility.IsManagementMode;

    UDTT_USER_GROUPS groups = new UDTT_USER_GROUPS();
    if (!isAdmin)
    {
        groups.PopulateByDataTable(Utility.GetSecurityTable(SPContext.Current.Web, isAdmin));
    }

    MOSSRepository repo = new MOSSRepository(this.ConnectionString);

    GET_REPORTParams pars = new GET_REPORTParams();
    pars.IS_ADMIN = isAdmin;
    pars.GROUPS = groups;
    pars.ID_REPORT = Convert.ToInt32(id);

    GET_REPORTResult result = repo.GET_REPORT(pars);

    if (result.Items != null && result.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        file = result.Items[0].FILE;

        return file;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    throw new Exception(ErrorHelper.GetHtmlMessage(exc), exc);
}
}
```

And this is the button click code:

```
protected void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.SPGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked)
            {
                zip.AddEntry(((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfName")).Value, getFileBytes(((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfID")).Value));
            }
        }

        zip.Save(@"C:\Test\Reports.zip");
    }
}
```

The ID in the FindControl method are correct but it doesn't works.
I cannot debug and I don't know why. It's says "No symbols has been loaded...", I'm working on SharePoint 2013.

So seen that at the moment I have only two records I tried to generate the two reports manually:

```
protected void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddEntry("File1", getFileBytes("1"));
        zip.AddEntry("File3", getFileBytes("3"));

        zip.Save(@"C:\Test\Reports.zip");
    }
}
```

And it works!
I've not exeptions in ULS so I think that my code never enters in the foreach loop.

Can you help to find a solution?

Thank you

Comment: If you can't debug (which seems odd to me) then why not try showing a message box or log an entry to a file when it enters into the foreach loop?

Comment: You are right. So I tried to write in IE console with Console.WriteLine and Debug.WriteLine but I can't  see any log that I wrote. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I know, it's strange that I can't debug. I tried Visual Studio, CKS Dev (Alt C + B) and Add-SPSolution deploy methods but I still can't hit a break point. I also tried with System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() but nothing.

Comment: Just try showing a message box before getting into the foreach loop, and then another inside the foreach loop. That will show whether you are first able to show what happens within the click event and then whether you're entering the foreach loop.